# How to remove the trailing dynamic zeros for the given numbers in MS-SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Given value in database table is `23.045000,45.6090, 23.900` .
  Output should be displayed as `23.045, 45.609, 23.9`

Comment: why not cast them as `select cast('23.045000' as float)`

Comment: Can you be more specific about which "output" you're asking?  The result of an SQL query or some tool that you use to view the database?

Answer (score 0):

Cast the value as Float. like this

```
select cast(23.045000 as float)-->23.045
select cast(45.6090 as float)-->45.609
select cast(23.900 as float)-->23.9
```